# Image dataset to CSV

Tags: python, csv, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I have created a new datasets with 20k images of 25 different classes. I want to now save this datasets into CSV file along with labels (like MNIST Sign language datasets.)
Please help...

Comment: Might be obvious, but what have you come up for yourself and/or what have you tried and encountered?

Comment: Hi! Please check below thread on converting images to Numpy array then to csv file.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-an-image-to-numpy-array-and-saveit-to-csv-file-using-python/